# Скрипт комбинации слов

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Возникла задача сделать "робота" на php, который будет "склеивать" слова в определенном порядке (см. изображение).
Получилось выводить значения через массивы http://prntscr.com/e4fjy7 , но этот вариант не подходит.

**Обновление**

```
<form action="" method="post">  
<input type="text" name="mass[]" /><br> 
<input type="text" name="mass[]" /><br>  
<input type="text" name="mass[]" /><br> <br>   

<input type="text" name="masss[]" /><br>
<input type="text" name="masss[]" /><br>
<input type="text" name="masss[]" /><br> <br>  

<input type="text" name="massss[]" /><br> 
<input type="text" name="massss[]" /><br>  
<input type="text" name="massss[]" /><br>  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Поехали!"><br>  

</form>  
<?php  

$arr1 = $_POST['mass'];
$arr2 = $_POST['masss'];
$arr3 = $_POST['massss'];


if (isset($_POST["submit"])){ 
$proverkakategoriy=mysql_query('SELECT virtuemart_category_id, category_name  FROM  ak89e_virtuemart_categories_ru_ru WHERE  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr1[0].'" )
AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr1[1].'" )
AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr1[2].'" )
AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr1[3].'" )
AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr2[0].'" )
AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr2[1].'" )
AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr2[2].'" )
AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr2[3].'" )
AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr3[0].'" )
AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr3[1].'" )
AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr3[2].'" )
AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr3[3].'" )
 ');        

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($proverkakategoriy))
{
echo '<p style="color:blue;">Совпадения: '.$row['virtuemart_category_id'].' '.$row['category_name'].'</p>';
echo '<p style="color:red;">Есть совпадения, скрипт не сработает</p>';
}

}

if (mysql_num_rows($proverkakategoriy)==0){
foreach($arr1 as $word1) {
    foreach($arr2 as $word2) {
        foreach($arr3 as $word3) {
            echo 'INSERT INTO ak89e_virtuemart_product_categories (category_name) VALUES ('.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.')<br>';

        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

**Обновление**

```
<form action="" method="post">  
<input type="text" name="mass[]" /><br> 
<input type="text" name="mass[]" /><br>  
<input type="text" name="mass[]" /><br> <br>   

<input type="text" name="masss[]" /><br>
<input type="text" name="masss[]" /><br>
<input type="text" name="masss[]" /><br> <br>  

<input type="text" name="massss[]" /><br> 
<input type="text" name="massss[]" /><br>  
<input type="text" name="massss[]" /><br>  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Поехали!"><br>  

</form>  
<?php  



$arr1 = $_POST['mass'];
$arr2 = $_POST['masss'];
$arr3 = $_POST['massss'];


foreach($arr1 as $word1) {
    foreach($arr2 as $word2) {
        foreach($arr3 as $word3) {
            echo $word1 . " " . $word2 . " " . $word3 . "<br>";
        }
    }
}


?>
```

Так тоже не срабатывает правильно http://prntscr.com/e4t22d

**Обновление**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, мне нужно чтобы по твоей схеме выполнялось два разных массива и вставлять их результат в запрос sql. как это сделать? На данный момент у меня есть два типа данных в foreach, это $word и $teg. сейчас они работают по очереди т.к. находятся в одном цикле, но мне нужно чтобы они работали отдельно, а потом мне нужно будет эти значения вставлять в INSERT запрос.

Происходит сейчас это так: пока $word обрабатываются циклом $teg дублируются, как $word обработались дальше начинают "перемножаться" $teg. нужно чтобы они не дублировались.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понятно. Можно подробнее - откда параметры берутся? что за список внизу? Почему не подходит вариант с массивами? И причем здесь mysql? Если данные из базы приходят, Вы не пробовали функцию `CONCAT()` в `mysql`?

Comment: данные вбиваются в <input type="text" name="mass[]" />.
требуется слева направо объединять слова как на картинке-примере.
вариант с массивами не подходит потому, что если в 1 столбце 2 слова, во втором 1, а в третьем 2, то при втором цикле объединения слов во втором столбце будет пусто. посмотрите пожалуйста скрин http://prntscr.com/e4fjy7

Comment: Ну все равно не понятно, почему вариант с массивами не проходит. Если сделать вложенные массивы...

Comment: он "не подходит" потому, что я не могу это сделать )
 получилось как на скрине, а доделать не хватает знаний

Comment: :):):):):) Ну тогда все -таки лучше написать "не получается", чем "не подходит" :)

Answer (score 1):

Подойдет?

```
$arr1 = Array("красные", "зеленые", "желтые");
$arr2 = Array("твердые", "мягкие");
$arr3 = Array("яблоки");

foreach($arr1 as $word1) {
    foreach($arr2 as $word2) {
        foreach($arr3 as $word3) {
            echo $word1 . " " . $word2 . " " . $word3 . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

**Результат:**

красные твердые яблоки
красные мягкие яблоки
зеленые твердые яблоки
зеленые мягкие яблоки
желтые твердые яблоки
желтые мягкие яблоки

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53229/discussion-on-answer-by-cyadvert---).